# How to insert an XML collection to table from a single insert statement?

Tags: c#, xml, t-sql

i have this table structure in SQL server

```
Table-A
AID    int (PK)--> set to autoincrement
Name varchar(200)

Table - B
BID  int PK  --> NOT set to auto increment
AID  int PK FK
Number1   int
Holographic  decimal(16,2)
```

The relationship between `A` and `B` is `1 : M`. 
So from my C# app `Table-B` data is send as `XML` with the following structure.

```
<TABLEB>
<RECORD>
  <BINID>23</BINID>
  <NUMBER1>123</NUMBER1>
  <HOLOGRAPHIC>2345.12</HOLOGRAPHIC>
</RECORD>
<RECORD>
  <BINID>3</BINID>
  <NUMBER1>346233</NUMBER1>
  <HOLOGRAPHIC>12.345</HOLOGRAPHIC>
</RECORD>
</TABLEB>
```

In my `SQL`, first i insert `Name` record to `Table-A` and then insert to `Table-B`. To obtain `AID` i must first insert to `Table-A`. Is there a way to save the `xml` records all at once with `AID` value? { because `xml` does not have `AID` value in it}

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can create a stored procedure to do that. I don't know how you insert Name to the first table, but here's how sp can insert all the records:

```
Create procedure insertSomething
@name as nvarchar(max),
@xmlData as xml
as
begin
declare @aid int;
-- insert data to table A
insert into tableA (Name) Values(@name);
select @aid = scope_identity(); -- gets newly created identity value
-- Shred xml data
Declare @docH int; -- Create document handle
-- get xml data
Declare @x as xml = @xmlData;
-- prepare xml doc
EXEC [sys].[sp_xml_preparedocument] @docH OUTPUT, @x
--get xml data in table format and insert into your destination table
insert into tableB (bid, aid, Number, Holographic)
SELECT BINID, @aid, NUMBER1, HOLOGRAPHIC
FROM    OPENXML(@docH, '/TABLEB/RECORD', 3) 
WITH(BINID int, NUMBER1 int, HOLOGRAPHIC decimal(16,2))
EXEC [sys].[sp_xml_removedocument] @docH
end
```

Then, run it as below:

```
DECLARE @z AS XML = '<TABLEB>
<RECORD>
<BINID>23</BINID>
<NUMBER1>123</NUMBER1>
<HOLOGRAPHIC>2345.12</HOLOGRAPHIC>
</RECORD></TABLEB>'

EXEC [dbo].[insertSomething] @name = N'name', -- nvarchar(max)
@xmlData = @z -- xml
```